# orm with entity framework 4 and code first

Tags: c#, orm, mapping, object-relational-model

I want to write a library to store any objects to a database. I still did the mapping for known objects using code first and the classes `DbContext` and `DbSet`. But in this case I don't know the structure of the objects I have to map. Is there a way to do this with the classes above?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do it is to create mapping classes dynamically and loading them into the ORM, but I'm not sure this is possible with EF4 since I'm a NHibernate guy.

By the way, I can't see a motive behind this. Why would you need such a thing?

If you need to store objects that have different (and unknown) schema you can use the Serialized LoB pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html) using a TEXT field in a relational database or go schema less with a NoSql document database such as MongoDB.